# Extracting an html table in another language using R

Tags: r, data-processing

I am using R to extract HTML Tables from a website.
However, the language for the HTML Table is in Hindi and the text is displayed as unicodes.
Any way where I can set/install the font family and get the actual text instead of the unicode.

The code I follow is :

```
library('XML')
table<-readHTMLTable(<the html file>)
n.rows <- unlist(lapply(table, function(t) dim(t)[1]))
table[[which.max(n.rows)]]
```

The sample site is : http://mpbhuabhilekh.nic.in/bhunakshaweb/reports/mpror.jsp?base=wz/CP8M/wj/DP8I/wz/CoA==&vsrno=26-03-02-00049-082&year=2013&plotno=71

The output comes as :
"< U+092A>"
etc.

Note:For some reason, the readHTMLTable works only when I remove the first two unwanted tables in the HTML file. So if you have to test with the file, please edit out the first two tables or simply delete the first two table headers from the file.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

update:

The issue seems to be related to locale set in R on windows OS Machines. Unable to figure out how to get it working though!

Comment: Which version of R/OS are you using? I cannot reproduce your problem (R 3.0.2 on Fedora Core 18, XML package 3.98-1.1). I can use `readHTMLTable` without editing out anything from the HTML and I see Hindi characters in the output of `readHTMLTable`. What is your locale set to (run `sessionInfo` or  `Sys.getlocale()`)?

Comment: @nico .. these are my system specs...
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)  - windows 8

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

other attached packages:
[1] XML_3.98-1.1

Comment: @nico  so I guess it might be something to do with the locale setting? could you tell me what you have set it to?

Comment: I have it set to `"LC_CTYPE=en_GB.utf8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=en_GB.utf8;LC_COLLATE=en_GB.utf8;LC_MONETARY=en_GB.utf8;LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.utf8;LC_PAPER=en_GB.utf8;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.utf8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"`. I guess UTF-8 is what makes the difference. Try: `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", 'en_US.UTF-8')`

Comment: @nico i guess there's some issue with windows..i get a warning "OS reports request to set locale to "en_US.UTF-8" cannot be honored" ...

Comment: @nico ... i think its an existing bug in windows :( .. https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14344

Comment: OK, I do not know enough about locales to help you with this, I fear, but at least you have some clues about where the problem lies!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56875/discussion-between-user2866631-and-nico).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I have found for this locale related bug would be to callthe corresponding encoding..

```
library('XML')
table<-readHTMLTable(<the html file>)
n.rows <- unlist(lapply(table, function(t) dim(t)[1]))
output <- table[[which.max(n.rows)]]
for (n in names(output)) Encoding(levels(output[[n]])) <-"UTF-16"
```

The output in R console might still look gibberish, but the advantage is that once you  export the dataset (say a csv), it would all appear in Hindi on other editors.